# How can I redirect this to a new tab?

Tags: php

I'm working on redirecting posts to url's and this currently does the job nicely but I cannot work out how to get it to open the url in a new tab.

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;

function bhrdr2p_redirect_post_to_url() {
    if( !is_singular() ) return;

    global $post;
    $redirect = esc_url( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'redirect', true ) );
    if( $redirect ) {
        wp_redirect( $redirect, 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bhrdr2p_redirect_post_to_url' );


//redirect any drafted posts
add_action('template_redirect', 'bhrdr2p_rtrash_redirect');
function bhrdr2p_rtrash_redirect(){
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
        if (is_404()){
            global $wp_query, $wpdb;
            $page_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wp_query->request );
            $post_status = get_post_status( $page_id );
          $redirect = esc_url( get_post_meta( $page_id, 'redirect', true ) );

            if($post_status == 'draft' && $redirect){
                wp_redirect( $redirect , 301);
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can redirect to a new `tab` using PHP. It is up to the user if he wants to open a link in a diff tab

Comment: It is the popup blocker’s _job_ to catch any such attempts to open new windows or tabs _automatically_, without being triggered by a proper user interaction that indicates the user actually wanted this to happen. There is no way for it to know that you want to show legitimate posts, and not “Buy ch34p v1agr4 h3re!!1” popups. Unless you are in an environment where you have control over the popup blocker configuration or want to ask users to add an exception for your site, this will not work for a lot of visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP is server-side, you can't.

Both the `header()` function and Wordpress' `wp_redirect()` do not offer such functionality.

---

You could try using JavaScript, it might work:

Change the Wordpress redirect:

```
wp_redirect( $redirect , 301);
```

To a small JavaScript script.

```
echo "<script> window.open(".$redirect.", '_blank') </script>";
```

Comment: OK thank you. How can I redirect posts to urls in another tab then? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Might be able to do it with JS, I updated the answer.

Comment: I tried it but it just displays a blank page where the post would be.

Comment: @TerencePearce Figured it would do that. Was worth the try. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Might be able to find a different solution.

Answer (score -1):

you must use the javascript here to redirect in new tab

```
if($post_status == 'draft' && $redirect){            
 <script>
     window.open( '<?php echo $redirect; ?>', '_blank' );
 </script>
 die();
}
```

Comment: that's for new window, not tab

Comment: first try the code then answer here.. its for the new tab.. not for the new window

Comment: It'll depend on how the user has their browser configured, for some people that'll be a new tab, others a new window.

Comment: @ashirharoon keep in mind this is JS,you're using, not PHP

Comment: @mrid php doesnt offer such functionality, so you must use JS at some places

Comment: This will likely neither get you a new window or tab, for a majority of users. Their popup blocker is going to eat any such attempts for breakfast …